# insert special characters in oracle database

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to insert the ampersand character '&' in oracle database

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES ('XYZ', 'A & B');
```

While executing this query I see a popup and it asks me to enter value .

How can I enter special characters like & in the insert statement for oracle db?

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL*Plus` or SQL Developer

```
set define off
```

to let the client know that you don't want it to interpret the ampersand character as the beginning of a substitution variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHR` function as following:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES ('XYZ', 'A ' || CHR(38) || ' B');
```

38 is ascii value of &.

Cheers!!